# How to move all items of one column to columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I am trying to move the items of a column to the columns of dataframe. I am struggling for hours but could not do so.

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [10,20,30,40,50],
    'Y': [list('abd'), list(), list('ab'),list('abefc'),list('e')]
})

print(df)
    X                Y
0  10        [a, b, d]
1  20               []
2  30           [a, b]
3  40  [a, b, e, f, c]
4  50              [e]
```

How to get the result like this:

```py
    X  a  b  c  d  e
0  10  1  1  0  1  0
1  20  0  0  0  0  0
2  30  1  1  0  0  0
3  40  1  1  1  0  1
4  50  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```py
out = df[['X']].join(df['Y'].apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(sep=','))
```

```
print(out)

    X  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  10  1  1  0  1  0  0
1  20  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  30  1  1  0  0  0  0
3  40  1  1  1  0  1  1
4  50  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

### `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df[mlb.classes_] = mlb.fit_transform(df['Y'])
```

### Pandas alternative

```
df.join(df['Y'].explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).max())
```

---

```
    X                Y  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  10        [a, b, d]  1  1  0  1  0  0
1  20               []  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  30           [a, b]  1  1  0  0  0  0
3  40  [a, b, e, f, c]  1  1  1  0  1  1
4  50              [e]  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: This is great and upvoted. But i am looking for pandas (or numpy,scipy) method and I have not used sklearn in this project. The alternative in pandas+numpy will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My straight forward solution :
Check if the current col is in your Y list or add a 0 :

```
for col in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
     df[col] = pd.Series([1 if col in df["Y"][x] else 0 for x in range(len(df.index))])

df = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Edit: Okay, the groupby is cleaner

Comment: How do you get abcde beforehand for general case?

Comment: parse Y with a SET `s = set()`, split string then add each element with `s.add()`