# How to turn the item in the column to multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do this.
So, currently my df look like this.

```
col_names = ['movie_id', 'movie_title', 'genres']
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/testing/ml-1m/movies.csv', sep='::', names=col_names, encoding='latin-1')
```

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
8::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
9::Sudden Death (1995)::Action
10::GoldenEye (1995)::Action|Adventure|Thriller
```

while the columns are such "movie_id, name, and genre".

I want it to look like this.

The columns would be ***movie_id, name,Action,Adventure,Animation,Children's,Comedy,Crime,Documentary,Drama,Fantasy,Film-Noir,Horror,Musical,Mystery,Romance,Sci-Fi,Thriller,War,Western***

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::0::0::1::1::1::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0
2::Jumanji (1995)::0::1::0::1::0::0::0::0::1::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0::0
.
.
...
```

Basically, I want to turn genre column to multiple columns and ***1*** will be there if it match the columns.

Is there anyway to do this with pandas?

Comment: Do you have any draft code we could look at ?

Comment: Here's the dataset to load. https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/1m/. I upload the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do it like that:

```
res = (df
       .join(df['genre'].str.get_dummies())
       .drop('genre',axis=1))

print(res)

print(res)

   movie_id                                name  Action  Adventure  Animation  Children's  Comedy  Crime  Drama  Fantasy  Romance  Thriller
0         1                    Toy Story (1995)       0          0          1           1       1      0      0        0        0         0
1         2                      Jumanji (1995)       0          1          0           1       0      0      0        1        0         0
2         3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)       0          0          0           0       1      0      0        0        1         0
3         4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)       0          0          0           0       1      0      1        0        0         0
4         5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)       0          0          0           0       1      0      0        0        0         0
5         6                         Heat (1995)       1          0          0           0       0      1      0        0        0         1
6         7                      Sabrina (1995)       0          0          0           0       1      0      0        0        1         0
7         8                 Tom and Huck (1995)       0          1          0           1       0      0      0        0        0         0
8         9                 Sudden Death (1995)       1          0          0           0       0      0      0        0        0         0
9        10                    GoldenEye (1995)       1          1          0           0       0      0      0        0        0         1
```

If you don't want to delete the original `genre` column, just remove the last part with `drop`

Comment: That's nice! I cannot understand the role of the .groupby(level=0).max() part. Could you help me a little?
The resulting df with or without that parts looks like the same to me.

Comment: oh wow, I did the wrong thing and got the right result :D sorry! the idea was to `explode` the column `genre`. Doing that one row with `Animation|Children's|Comedy` would result in 3 rows with the 3 categories (all 3 have the same index). Because you only want one row you would have to groupby the index (level=0 here) and call max on it. My solution worked because `explode` didn't do anything (the value in a cell has to be a list which can be exploded and not a string) but `str_get_dummies` takes `|` as default sepr and skip the need of exploding it in the first step. answer will be updated

Comment: If you are interested, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218898/how-to-move-all-items-of-one-column-to-columns-in-pandas/72218997#72218997). the accepted answer `joins` the list to a string at first and then just calls `str.get_dummies` while the 2nd answer (keyword: pandas alternative) first explodes the list and then group them. Since your data starts already as string, no need to change to list, explode and group them.

Comment: Bookmarked the answer, thank you!